Valid packages versions not accepted by package manager as vaild
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy

I upgraded a package (kstars) that updated the gphoto2 libraries to version 2.5.31:
$ apt list --installed libgphoto2-6
Listing... Done
libgphoto2-6/jammy,now 2.5.31+202410230526~ubuntu22.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
N: There is 1 additional version. Please use the '-a' switch to see it
$ apt list --installed libgphoto2-port12 
Listing... Done
libgphoto2-port12/jammy,now 2.5.31+202410230526~ubuntu22.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
N: There is 1 additional version. Please use the '-a' switch to see it

However this automatically removed all of wine (and other packages) which has a requirement for version >= 2.5.10
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libsane1:i386 : Depends: libgphoto2-6:i386 (>= 2.5.10) but it is not installable
                 Depends: libgphoto2-port12:i386 (>= 2.5.10) but it is not installable
                 Recommends: sane-airscan:i386 but it is not installable
 wine-stable-i386:i386 : Depends: libgphoto2-6:i386 (>= 2.5.10) but it is not installable
                         Depends: libgphoto2-port12:i386 (>= 2.5.10) but it is not installable

Unless I'm reading it wrong 2.5.31 is => 2.5.10.
So what went wrong and what is my fix?

It's asking for the i386 32bit packages not the 64bit packages. What is the output of apt policy libgphoto2-{6,port12}:i386?  It may want packages that aren't available on your system at the moment due to your configurations.
